# How would I use $index inside ng-model?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have created a set of inputs for every key in my array so that I can filter arrays by specific values (so there is a "First Name" input box for searching against "first_name")

Below is the HTML for the ng-repeat and the dynamic ng-model I am trying to create.

```
<form role="form" ng-submit="doSearch()">
  <div ng-repeat="keyName in keyNames">
      <label for="{{ keyName }}">{{ keyName }} ({{$index}})</label>
         <input type="text" ng-model="search.filterKeyNames[$index]">
      </div>
   <button>Filter</button>
</form>
```

However, when I try to enter anything into the input fields, two strange things happen:

1. I cannot type any values inside the inputs
2. Console log error reports "Cannot set property '0' of undefined"

Peep the fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/2690/)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what exactly do you want as a result.

Comment: can you provide what keyNames and search object values ?

Comment: Could you make a plunker of your problem?

Comment: In your controller scope do you define $scope = {search:{filterKeyNames:{}}}; it seems to be complaining that there is no object called search.filterKeyNames

Comment: @shaunhusain you don't use brackets in a controller

Comment: Joe Isaacson those are object definitions, though I did have it wrong a bit I believe should have been $scope.search = {filterKeyNames:{}} this way $scope object has a property called search which is an object that itself has a property filterKeyNames which is an empty object, this should avoid the set property of undefined error.

Comment: @Mindstormy fiddle of the problem http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/2690/ cheers

Comment: I have to agree with Nitish Kumar, I really dont understand what you are trying to accomplish here. I have looked at the code now a couple times and I am lost as to it's purpose...